# Find merges in master, but not in tag

Tags: git, merge

I'm trying to automate the creation of a changelog during for each release. During our release process, we create tags for every release. Individual commits do not happen on master, features are merged using `--no-ff`, so all features have a merge commit.

How do I get a list of all merge commits in master, that are not in a tag (ie, the previous release)?

I tried this based on some other SO answers, but doesn't quite give me what I want:

```
git log --pretty=oneline --all <tag>..master --merges
```

Comment: Can you provide an example output of what you desire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `--ancestry-path` should work:

```
git log --pretty=oneline --all <tag>..master --merges --ancestry-path
```

However, since you are only concerned with the flow of the a single branch, you will only care about the first parent's history. Therefore, this command will also work:

```
git log --pretty=oneline --all <tag>..master --first-parent
```

Comment: Looks like the first one does what I want. The second one shows a bunch of extra commits.

Comment: @zsquare It should only show commits from master. Do you mind showing me an example?

Comment: Sure, will do tomorrow. Don't have access to the repo atm.